# reactjs Bootstrap Cards in grid

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

So I want to achieve a dynamic rendering of the bootstrap card type depending on a number of players. 4 players should be rendered one below the other. But as soon as I hit the 5th player I want the cards to spread into two columns.

How would I achieve this?

The cards themselves and their corresponding bodies will opt for a 100% width of the wrapping container. So as long as there are only 4 players the cards will use up 100% width.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I won't code the entire solution, but I sure can give you an architectural pattern you can follow to build your solution upon.

```
class PlayersView extends React.Component {

  buildFewPlayersGrid = () => {
    ... create gridprops based on logic ...
    return <SmallGrid {...gridprops} />
  };

  buildLotsOfPlayersGrid = () => {
    ... create gridprops based on logic ...
    return <TheBigGrid {...gridprops} />
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.players.length < 5) {
      return this.buildFewPlayersGrid();
    }
    return this.buildLotsOfPlayersGrid();
  }

}
```

Let's note some things here, I would recommend those functions only if you need to create those views in a way that it won't make it possible for you to just import each Grid separately from its own components. If you can do it differently then I would recommend...

```
class PlayersView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.players.length < 5) {
      return <SmallGrid players={this.props.players} />;
    }
    return <TheBigGrid players={this.props.players} />;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you, so to answer your question, you can benefit from componentization and splitting your code into several components like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far. I do understand what you are saying and this way it would definitely work. I thought more of a css / scss approach though. I was thinking there might be a possibility to dynamically render the grid using bootstraps css options. But after research I didn't find anything and was hoping for someone to know more about css and bootstrap. But if this is, what I am ending up with I will gladly take your architectural advice and solve the challenge this way.

Comment: In bootstrap you need to add the classes to the "html" elements, because you're using the react version of bootstrap, you can benefit from componentization. And dinamically add the grid classes every element will need on each case. You can't do this with plain CSS.